# Cythonize generates two separate build folders for .c and .o files

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

The structure of my package is the following:

```
.
setup.py
setup.sh
neuralflow/
    c_get_gamma.pyx
```

My goal is to compile cython extension and put all the built files into neuralflow folder.

Setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
import numpy as numpy
        
extensions = [Extension("c_get_gamma", ["neuralflow/c_get_gamma.pyx"],include_dirs = [numpy.get_include(), "neuralflow/"])]

from Cython.Build import cythonize
extensions = cythonize(extensions,build_dir="neuralflow/build")


setup(
    ext_modules = extensions,
    packages=["neuralflow"],
    package_dir={'neuralflow': 'neuralflow'}
)
```

Setup.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
python setup.py build_ext --build-lib neuralflow
```

As a result, I get the following structure:

```
.
setup.py
setup.sh
build/
    temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/
         neuralflow/
             build/
                 neuralflow/
                     c_get_gamma.o
neuralflow/
    c_get_gamma.pyx
    c_get_gamma.cpython-37m-darwin.so 
    build/
        neuralflow/
            c_get_gamma.c
```

I don't understand why is there a build folder in the project's root folder with that weird structure. Am I doing the installation properly?

Python 3.7.6, Cython 0.29.15

Comment: You didn’t provide —build-temp? https://docs.python.domainunion.de/3/distutils/configfile.html

Comment: @ead Yeah, that was the issue. Thanks. Do you know how to clean these files?